# Efficient algorithm for pairwise computation

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have a list of agents `a = {a1, a2, a3,..., an}`, in which each agent may be paired up with zero or more other agents. For example, for `n = 6`, I can have:

```
a1: a2, a3, a5
a2: a1, a3, a4
a3: a1, a2. a5
a4: a2
a5: a1, a3
a6:
```

Each pair interact with each other, and each agent obtains a value as the result of this interaction (e.g. they can play a game, but the details of interaction can be abstracted away here). **I am interested in computing and storing the results of these interactions based on a given pairwise structure** such as above.

Obviously, a naive algorithm would be to go through each agent and then compute the pairwise interaction with each of his interacting partners one-by-one. **However, it is also obvious that this approach will duplicate some (or potentially many) computation.** Using the example above:

by the time we finish for agent `a1`, we would've already obtained the results for `(a1, a2)`, `(a1, a3)`, and `(a1, a5)`, thus rendering the later computation among these pairs redundant when we do it for agent `a2`, `a3`, and `a5`,

An improved algorithm would be to sort the input structure in an ascending order in both dimensions (i.e. along agents themselves and along their respective partners) as in the example above, so that for each agent (e.g. `a3`), we only need to compute for the interactions between this agent (`a3`) and the ones that are 'higher' than him (`a5`), since we know the interactions between himself and 'lower' partners (`(a1, a3)`, `(a2, a3)`) have already been computed.

I wonder if there is different and better algorithm for this problem? By better, I mean more efficient computation in terms of both time and space.

Comment: As soon as you sort something you've made the algorithm O(n log(n)), so lose to any O(n) implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this tries to add each pair to the set twice, but I feel that this may be more efficient than the conditional. Does anyone want to try timing the alternatives?

```
agents = {
    'a1': ['a2', 'a3', 'a5'],
    'a2': ['a1', 'a3', 'a4'],
    'a3': ['a1', 'a2', 'a5'],
    'a4': ['a2'],
    'a5': ['a1', 'a3'],
    'a6': []
}
pairs = {(k,v) for k in agents for v in agents[k]}
```

This is still O(n), so in terms of efficiency beats anything involving sorting

You'd probably get a minor speedup by using

```
pairs = {(k,v) for k,vs in agents.iteritems() for v in vs}
```

Comment: My test shows your this version taking 0.4 seconds and my version taking 1.5 seconds for 100,000 iterations. Care to enlighten me as to why this version is so much faster?

Comment: @Trevor, The underlying C code that checks/adds the items in the set comprehension is very fast.

Comment: @gnibbler, thanks for the suggestions, but the above still produces **duplicated** interaction pairs, e.g. `(a1, a2)` as well as `(a2, a1)`.

Comment: you can do this: pairs = {frozenset(k,v) for k,vs in agents.iteritems() for v in vs}

Comment: @MLister, you can either use `frozenset` as suggested by Amr, or add a conditional like `pairs = {(k,v) for k in agents for v in agents[k] if k<v}`. You should test and see which is faster

Comment: @MLister, actually the list comprehension version is even faster `[(k,v) for k in agents for v in agents[k] if k<v]`

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the agent ids with something like this:

```
agents = {
    'a1': ['a2', 'a3', 'a5'],
    'a2': ['a1', 'a3', 'a4'],
    'a3': ['a1', 'a2', 'a5'],
    'a4': ['a2'],
    'a5': ['a1', 'a3'],
    'a6': []
}

interactions = []
for agent, connections in agents.iteritems():
    interactions.extend((agent, connection) for connection in connections if agent < connection)

print interactions
# [('a1', 'a2'), ('a1', 'a3'), ('a1', 'a5'), ('a3', 'a5'), ('a2', 'a3'), ('a2', 'a4')]
```

Comment: You don't need inner `for` loop: `interactions.extend((agent, connection) for connection in connections if agent < connection)`. I updated your answer.

Comment: And what if I have a different group of agents: `a = {a1, a2, a3,..., an}` and `b = {b1, b2, b3,..., bm}`, which can operate with each other?

Comment: so this is basically the improved version of algorithm as I outlined above?

Answer (score 0):

[itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to the rescue

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> agents=['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5']
>>> list(combinations(agents, 2))
[('a1', 'a2'), ('a1', 'a3'), ('a1', 'a4'), ('a1', 'a5'), 
 ('a2', 'a3'), ('a2', 'a4'), ('a2', 'a5'),
 ('a3', 'a4'), ('a3', 'a5'),
 ('a4', 'a5')]
>>>
```

Comment: He does not want to generate all possible pairs. He needs to transform his structure to non-repeating list of pairs.

Comment: That is what the above does - transforms the structure `agents` into a non-repeating list of pairs.

Comment: @NickCraigWood, As far as I understood, the initial structure is something like this: `a = {
 "a1": ["a2", "a3", "a5"],
 "a2": ["a1", "a3", "a4"],
 "a3": ["a1", "a2", "a5"],
 "a4": ["a2"],
 "a5": ["a1", "a3"],
 "a6": []
}
`

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood, the pairwise-interaction structure input can be **arbitrary**. The example you provided would be a special case I suppose.

Comment: I think you are right about the intent of the question, but also I think that `combinations` will provide the most efficient calculation of all the possible pairwise interactions which seems to be what the OP wants.  I'll leave this answer for a bit just in case anyone else agrees, othewise I'll delete it!

Comment: You could still use `combinations` on the given pairs, then aggregate the results into a `set`.  This will give a set of unique pairs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, why don't you take into account a 2D matrix? At first stage, just set intersection cells equals to 1 if two agents can cooperate with each other. 
At second stage, just set a cycle around the matrix and calculate some values only between those agents, who has a interconnection (i.e. where cell is equal to 1). And instead of 1 there will be a real value. So in that case you don't need to do redundant calculations. The only redundant part is to fill calculated value twice in matrix.

Comment: so you need to first populate this n x n matrix, and then iterate through each cell to find the ones with value `1`, and then perform the computation for them. sounds like a lot of work to me. in addition, the result of each interaction computation should be two values, one for each interacting agent.

Comment: A lot of work? You don't need to populate NxN matrix, just create a zero matrix and set its `i,j` & `j,i` elements to `1` or leave untouched while forming a set of agents pair. Then, yes, you need to iterate through half of matrix (notice, the matrix is symmetric in your case). And you can store any kind of elements in your cells.

Comment: BTW, I don't insist, the matrix approach is the best, just give you another point of view :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @gnibbler's answer, I come up with this:

```
agents = {
    'a1': ['a2', 'a3', 'a5'],
    'a2': ['a1', 'a3', 'a4'],
    'a3': ['a1', 'a2', 'a5'],
    'a4': ['a2'],
    'a5': ['a1', 'a3'],
    'a6': []
}

pairs = {tuple(sorted((k,v))) for k in agents for v in agents[k]}
```

Sorting is still needed but only restricted to a pair.